# Transfer images using sony camera API

Tags: camera, sony

We would like to use an sony camera in an installation, but is transferring the recorded movie files from the camera only possible using one of the following camera's:

- HDR-AZ1
- HDR-AS200
- FDR-X1000

See the following overview:
https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Any chance that the newer models will ever support this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring images is also supported on ILCE-QX1 and DSC-QX30.  Cannot say if newer models will support this functionality or not.